# How to fix imagick library cache exhausted issue in PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, docker, imagick

Good afternoon, colleagues!

**Source Data:**

> There is a Docker with a web application inside on PHP7.3-apache;
>
> Image " **ORIGINAL** " with a resolution of 7500x10500px in tiff
>   format and size of 149 MB.
>
> Test image " **MIDDLE** " with a resolution of 7600x7600px in tiff
>   format (LZW compression) and size 8.9 Mb.
>
> Test image " **LARGE** " with a resolution of 11000x11000px in tiff
>   format (LZW compression) and size 14.9 Mb.

There is a script for image processing:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage(Storage::path($filePath.$fileName));
$img->setImageFormat ('png');
$img->writeImage(public_path($fileName));
$img->destroy();
```

When running a script with the image "**MIDDLE**" there are no problems, but when you use ["**ORIGINAL**" and "**LARGE**"], files

> *"cache resources exhausted
>   `/var/www/html/storage/app/upload/image-tiff/2019-09-39/LARGE_f2ed11af1f6bbbccccdeb621eb4a843b02.tiff
>   '@ error / cache.c / OpenPixelCache / 4083"*

**Initial resource limits:**

> Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY = 268435456
>
> Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP = 536870912
>
> Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA = 128000000
>
> Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 1073741824

If you set these limits at least 1 unit higher, it resets to its original value.

For example:

```
Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY, 1024435456);
Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP, 1536870912);
Imagick::setResourceLimit(IMagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 256000000);
Imagick::setResourceLimit(IMagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 4073741824);
```

***I will be grateful for a description of the solution to my problem.***

Comment: One of the suggestions on a third-party resource was the following: in the /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.hml file inside the container, increase the limits.

Comment: The exception is stating a "files cache" limit was reached, not memory, map, area, or disk limit. Is that right?

Comment: @emcconville Thank you, corrected the error. The word files were not there.